# How to Copy object with booleans?

Tags: topology

[image]

I have an object with booleans applied to it. I want to make a copy of it so I can come back to it if I mess something up

The issue is that the booleans do not copy alongside the mesh.

How do I make a copy of the mesh that also brings across the boolean operations?

Comment: You probably also have to copy over the boolean objects. In your scene, they're hidden or something.

Comment: Im looking for an instant one click way rather than having to manually move the boolean objects

Comment: You can instantly one-click "apply" the modifier. Then you will be able to make a copy with booleans applied. But you won't be able to edit them.

Comment: I want to maintain non destructive editing

Comment: Have tested MeshMachine's `duplicate booleans`. Have tested asset browsers `Mark as asset`. Neither work. May need custom coded addon to do this but im pretty sure alot of people would be pleased using such a plugin so its worth developing.

Comment: I am *probably* going to learn blender python to create this addon. Ill update if i actually manage to make it successfully

Comment: "instant one click way rather than having to manually move the boolean objects" - what is not instant in moving boolean object together and how many extra clicks do you have to do to select the boolean object? Seems pretty instant and pretty one-click to me...

Comment: If you manage to get your object + its modifiers under a collection you can right click on the collection in the outliner and choose "Duplicate Collection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MeshMachine allows you to copy objects with booleans with it's `Duplicate Booleans` function.**

`Duplicate Boolean`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is not a one click way by default. Current workflow for such thing is organized file.

**For backup** reason - simply store all related objects in a collection.
Duplicate collection.

**For translation** such thing - parent all boolean objects to active base mesh by one click.

---

To automate it you would need a script ... as you mention, but seems to me easier to place base mesh into a collection at the beginning (so others will store there auto) than maintain a script ready for such operation, but I'm not using booleans so heavily, so I could be wrong (•‿•)